# How to remove part of PerformanceAnalytics Chart?

Tags: r, charts, performanceanalytics

I have the following chart generated by the PerformanceAnalytics Package.

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(input, colorset=rainbow12equal, wealth.index = TRUE,
                          lwd=2, ylog=TRUE, methods = "StdDev", main = "Model 1 - 5% - 95% ")
```

[image]

Since the Daily Return Chart can not display multiple lines I would like to remove it and have just the Cumulative Return and Drawdown sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separately plot the individual graphs, and not plot the graph in the middle in your example. I've used data from the 'PerformanceAnalytics' package.

'chart.CumReturns' will plot a set of periodic returns (cumulative return); this is your first graph.

'chart.Drawdown' will plot drawdowns through time, which is your third graph.

```
library(‘PerformanceAnalytics’)
data(edhec)
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
chart.CumReturns(edhec[,c(1,13)])
chart.Drawdown(edhec[,c(1,13)])
```